# Queuing mechanism in Node.js and MongoDb

Tags: node.js

Recently I am having trouble in queuing mechanism in node.
Test Case:
Let's say that I want to add an item in my cart.And let suppose that there is the last item left in the cart and 4users clicked "add to cart" at the very same time and the milliseconds of the request is also same.
How should I prevent this such that only 1 user gets the access of that product and rest 3 users should receive an error.
Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how is business logic but I would suggest that don't apply queue logic on add to cart because after add to cart user may not pay.
Coming to your main topic, if you are facing these types of scenario then just use some queue service like Rebbitmq, Kafka, Redis, etc which will help you serve as first come first serve.
I hope this may help to solve your issue.